# Next.js cachea select queries en producción

Tags: javascript, nodejs, typescript, postgresql, next.js

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto de la universidad que es una pequeña página de un restaurante con un administrador para agregar comida y que se refleje en el frontend. La página está hecha usando *Next.js*, *Prisma.io* y *Postgres*. La API está hecha usando la misma API de *Next.js*.

La lógica de la página, resumida, es esta: Cada comida está situada en una categoría, o sea tengo la categoría "Tacos" y dentro de ella puedo poner "Tacos de pollo", "Tacos de res", etc.

En modo de desarrollo todo funciona como debería, las conexiones, consultas, administrador, etc. Pero cuando yo mando mi página a producción, las queries de select se quedan cacheadas. O sea, si desde el administrador yo agrego una comida nueva, esta se refleja en la tabla del administrador pero no en el frontend de los clientes. Incluso si yo visito la API desde Postman o Thunderclient, esta me retorna data sin la nueva comida que agregué.

Hice varias pruebas e incluso hice fetch con otros paquetes (como `node-postgres`) e igual, la data no se refresca, es como si Next.js hiciera una copia en caché de esos resultados.

Les dejo secciones de código importantes:

`/api/comidas` para crear una comida nueva

```
import { prismaExclude } from "@/utils";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import prisma from "../db-connection";

export const POST = async (req: Request) => {
  try {
    const { nombreProducto, descripcion, precio, categoriaId, imageSrc } =
      (await req.json()) as ReqInputs;

    await prisma.producto.create({
      data: {
        nombreProducto,
        descripcion,
        precio,
        categoria: {
          connect: {
            id: categoriaId,
          },
        },
        imageSrc,
      },
    });

    return NextResponse.json(
      {
        message: "Comida created successfully",
      },
      { status: 201 }
    );
  } catch (error) {
    return NextResponse.json(
      {
        message: `Error trying to create a food: ${error}`,
      },
      { status: 500 }
    );
  }
};
```

`/api/categorias/comidas` para obtener las categorías y las comidas que pertenecen a cada una:

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import prisma from "../../db-connection";

export const GET = async () => {
  const categorias = await prisma.categoria.findMany({
    include: {
      Producto: true,
    },
  });

  return NextResponse.json({
    message: "Categorias retreived successfully",
    categorias,
  });
};
```

Fetch de las comidas (sí se refrescan cuando se agrega una comida nueva):

```
import { ComidaFull } from "@/types";
import { useQuery } from "react-query";

export default function useComidas() {
  const { data, refetch } = useQuery<{
    message: string;
    comidas: ComidaFull[];
  }>(["comidas"], getComidas);

  return {
    comidas: data?.comidas,
    reloadComidas: refetch,
  };
}

export const getComidas = () => fetch("/api/comidas").then((res) => res.json());
```

Fetch de las categorías que incluyen comidas (Estas **NO** reflejan los cambios que se hacen desde el administrador):

```
import { CategoriaWithComida } from "@/types";
import { useQuery } from "react-query";

export default function useGetWithFoods() {
  const { data, refetch } = useQuery<{
    message: string;
    categorias: CategoriaWithComida[];
  }>(["categoria", "comida"], getCategoriaWithFood);

  return {
    categorias: data?.categorias,
    reloadCategoriasComidas: refetch,
  };
}

export const getCategoriaWithFood = () =>
  fetch("/api/categorias/comidas").then((res) => res.json());
```

NOTA: La bd de postgres que uso está corriendo en un Docker container

Comment: ¿Se están _commiteando_ los cambios?

Comment: @padaleiana Corro el modo de producción en mi computadora, o sea hago el build y lo corro con ```npm start``` e igual, hice commit de todo al server de vercel y pasa lo mismo